# chrome.tabs.sendMessage doesn't send message to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to send some data from runtime (background.js) back to my content script. For some reason, it doesn't work for me. Here's my code:

**manifest.json**

```
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "*://*.mysite.com/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches": ["*://*.mysite.com/*"],
            "js": ["script.js"]
        }
    ],
```

**background.js**

```
function sendToActiveTab(type, message) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { type: type, message: message });
    })
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
        if (request) {
            //do some stuff here
            sendToActiveTab('type', 'message');
        }
    }
)
```

**script.js**

```
document.write('hello');
var params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
        if (request) {
            //do some stuff here
        }
    }
)

if (params.get('someParam')) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
        {
            example: 'data'
        }
    )
} else {
    //do some stuff here
}
```

Here's what I tried:

- return true in background.js addListener & scripts.js addListener
- return Promise in background.js addListener & scripts.js addListener
- I checked - chrome.tabs.query returns the right tab and everything looks good there (although status of this tab is 'loading')

I've looked through many links online and still can't find a solution that works for me. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: The tab that sent a message isn't always the active tab (active means "currently focused") especially if you're currently debugging it in devtools or you have many tabs with this site. So instead of sending a new message to the content script you should use sendResponse to return the value in the callback of the content script's sendMessage as shown in the first and third code snippets of [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: Also make sure you've reloaded both the extension on chrome://extensions page and the tab(s).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for suggestion. Just tried it. No luck :( Made sure content script had callback for response and also made sure addListener in background returns true. No response being sent. I reload extension after every change

Comment: Without seeing the new code I can't guess further. Looks like a problem that's not related to the posted code. Use devtools debugger to set breakpoints in the content script listeners and actually debug your code, this is what solves 99.99% of problems after all.